# Is Luke 12:22-29 arranged as a chiasm?

Tags: luke, christology, chiasm

```
A) 22 And He said to His disciples, “For this reason I say to you, [j]do not worry about your [k]life, as to what you will eat; nor for your body, as to what you will put on

 B) 24 Consider the ravens, for they neither sow nor reap; they have no storeroom nor barn, and yet      God feeds them; how much more valuable you are than the birds!

  C) 25 And which of you by worrying can add a single [l]hour to his [m]life’s span?

  C) 26 If then you cannot do even a very little thing, why do you worry about other matters?

 B) 27 Consider the lilies, how they grow: they neither toil nor spin; but I tell you, not even Solomon in all his glory clothed himself like one of these.

A) 29 And do not seek what you will eat and what you will drink, and do not keep worrying.
```

The above texts seem to centre around worry and could this arrangement be a chiasm?

---

See [Chiastic Structure - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure)

See [Chiasmus in the Scripture - Chiasmus Exchange](https://www.chiasmusxchange.com/explanatory-notes/)

Comment: I have edited just to add information for those who may not know what a 'chiasm' is. (+1)

Comment: I think the answer is in your arrangement of the verses with A, B, and C preceding them.